# How do I load assests in codeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Am trying to load an image for a view file using this line of code:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('application/assests/images/logo.png'); ?>" alt="" />
```

Am getting a Access forbidden! error.
The assests folder is under the application folder: *root/application/assests/images/logo.png*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First edit config to set base_url() as static like:

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourprojectfolder/';

Or you can use the below base_url config to set dynamic project root url.

$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';

Do not include your web assests in application folder, There is your MVC....

You can use now for the image:

" alt="" />
or
assests/images/logo.png" alt="" />

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The assets folder should not be under application, as access to that folder is restricted by the .htaccess file in that directory.

Instead, move the assets folder up one level (so it's at the same point in the file structure as the application folder), and update the code accordingly.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('assests/images/logo.png'); ?>" alt="" />
```